# XAMPP loops me back to its Welcome Page

Tags: xampp

XAMPP keeps redirecting me to its Welcome Page whenever I attempt to redirect to another page (such as submitting a form or clicking in a navbar to be redirected to another webpage) and this happens throughout all my projects in my htdocs folder.

What I have tried:

1. I have commented the line `header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');` inside the default index.php found in xampp/htdocs folder.
2. I checked the current port I am using and it's free.
3. I ran my code in a different computer with XAMPP installed just to be certain that it wasn't my code that was causing this and it redirected me to the webpage I wanted or it submitted the form with no problems. But the XAMPP installed on this particular computer is an older version than the one I am using.
4. I have reinstalled XAMPP version 7.4.1 (Windows) and it still kept looping me back to the Welcome Page of XAMPP.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

May I know is there any file like '.htaccess' on your root of htdocs or root of website,

please try remove it or open and edit it if yes.

Or how about run it by incognito mode of browser, does it show same issue?
I think maybe cache if not then please try clean the cache.

Or Please check the httpd.conf or httpd-vhost.conf, please check is there any thing like below 'Redirect' or 'ErrorDocument' , e.g. 403 will redirect '/' or say 'No'

```
Redirect 403 /
ErrorDocument 403 "No"
```